# Can I change __name__ atribute of object in python?

Tags: python, object

Is it correct to change the value of `__name__` atribute of object like in the following example:

```
>>>
>>> def f(): pass
...
>>> f.__name__
'f'
>>> b = f
>>> b.__name__
'f'
>>> b.__name__ = 'b'
>>> b
<function b at 0x0000000002379278>
>>> b.__name__
'b'
>>>
```

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question...

Comment: As far as I know it will work, but it's probably not a good idea - I guess it will make tracebacks and so on harder to follow. Why do you want to?

Comment: `is it correct ? ` you mean by this is it possible well you already have the answer , `is it correct` mean is it worth it well i think it depend on the context of what you want to use it for.

Comment: why do you want to rename it? are you trying to copy the object?

Comment: `f` returns same memory address.

Comment: only documentation i've found is http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__name__#special-attributes, and it says it is read-only attribute

Comment: @rsk: It says nothing about read-only?

Comment: @rsk - http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy skip down to "Callable types", `__name__` is listed as Writable.

Comment: @AJ thanks suppose it is the answer

Comment: @tMC I want to do some magic, this attribute is used by underlying framework, so changing it I can change some logic

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this kind of "magic" is used in [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to make sure the wrapped function keeps its name, doc string, etc.

Comment: @job functools.wrap is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Changing a function's name doesn't make the new name callable:

```
>>> def f(): print 'called %s'%(f.__name__)
...
>>> f()
called f
>>> f.__name__ = 'b'
>>> f()
called b
>>> b()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

You'd have to define `b` in order to call it.  And as you saw, simply assigning `b=f` doesn't define a new function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change `__name__`. I sometimes change the `__name__` of a decorator instance to reflect the function it's decorating, e.g.

```
class CallTrace:

...

def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f
    self.__name__ = f.__name__ + ' (CallTraced)'
```

I'm not asserting this is good practice, but it has helped me debug code in the past. The idea is if you decorate a function `fn`, then type `fn.__name__` at the prompt, you can see immediately that it's decorated.